# converting air app to .apk file

Tags: apk

I am trying to make the application in flash builder by choosing the flex project.

Tried to convert swf file to .apk file . The procedure followed is

1. added supportedProfile to the xml
2. created the pfx file (test.pfx) with the password test
3. assigned the certificate to the swf
4. executed this command: adt -package -target apk-emulator  -storetype pkcs12 –keystore test.pfx pulsr.apk pulsr-app.xml pulsr.swf
5. password prompt appears, typed in test
6. packaging failed “The key could not be obtained. You may need to  use the -keystore argument with the specified keystore type.”

This is the error i got please anyone help me with this..........

Thanks in advance...